# Caret on the wrong place in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I thought that was a bug in the RC but the Release version has the same error.
Anyone saw the same as me? How to fix?

[image]

Comment: Does it happen if you place the opening brace on a new line? (Type `public void bar [newline] { [newline]`)

Comment: I've had issues with C++ syntax not getting highlight properly.

Comment: This is a known issue with C# Brace Completion that was not fixed in time for RTM. It's being tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be [Roslyn bug 3447 - Enter within {}s doesn't insert newline if } isn't set to format](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3447)